# Removal of background shadow of window in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

On dragging a window past the left edge of the screen, a transparent shadow of the window panel appears and I need to remove it. It doesn't appear on moving the window past the right edge.

I looked for any ExtJS property to configure it, but couldn't find any. I'm fairly new to ExtJS development so maybe it's a syntax issue; the best I could find is the box-shadow attribute but adding it with value set as "none" is having no effect on the shadow.

Current code snippet is this:

var win = new Ext.Window({

width: screen.width/2,

height: screen.height/2,

modal: true

)};

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [`ghost: false`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.7.0/classic/Ext.window.Window.html#cfg-ghost) on the window.